# When connecting IBOUTLETS, what is the significance of having a nothing, a dash?

Tags: iphone, xcode

When connecting outlets in interface builder(by cntrl-clicking) , sometimes I see a "-" proceeding the name of the outlet and sometimes there is nothing there.  Of course a dot signifies that there is a connection.  But what is the significance of a dash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Xcode user guide:

> If a connection identical to the one being made already exists, the
>   menu item is flagged with a dot. If a connection exists with that
>   name, but to a different object, it is flagged with a dash.